# Printing Canvas to XPS unwanted scaling and cut off

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, printing, xps

**Update**

Before writing a reply one might check out SamTheDev's answer and the comments of it. SamTheDev's answer fixed both problems, but I don't understand, why it fixes the first problem.

---

I am experiencing the following XPS problems and need your help in resolving the issues. A bounty is now running.

**Issue 1: 10 cm long line in WPF is not 10 cm long in XPS**

I am drawing this 10 cm long black line:
[image: 10 cm long black line WPF]

Making a screenshot of it, pasting it to Word and printing it shows me, that it is really 10 cm long:

[image: 10 cm long line after printing with word]

When however printing the generated XPS file, the line is only about 9.7 cm long:

[image: Screenshot if generated XPS file]

[image: Print of generated XPS file]

The code used for drawing the black line is as follows. I assumed a resolution of 96 dotchs per inch, I guess I need to do some scaling before creating the XPS file, but I don't know how to do that.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MWEXps.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MWEXps"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Sample 1 - 10 cm long black line" Height="300" Width="700">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
        <!-- will be filled by code behind -->        
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Code behind:
(basically only the constructor and printCanvas method are relevant)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // a 10 cm long line
        PathFigure lineFigure1 = new PathFigure();
        lineFigure1.StartPoint = cmPoint(3, 1);

        LineSegment lineSegment1 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment1.Point = cmPoint(13, 1);
        lineFigure1.Segments.Add(lineSegment1);

        drawPathFigure(lineFigure1, canvas, Colors.Black);

        // save as XPS
        printCanvas();
    }


    public void printCanvas()
    {
        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(@".\canvas-10cm.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

        writer.Write(canvas);
        doc.Close();
    }

    // helper creating a point in centimeters
    public Point cmPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        return new Point(cmToWpf(x), cmToWpf(y));
    }


    // helper converting a length in device independent pixels to centimeters
    public double wpfToCm(double wpfValue)
    {
        double factor = (96 / 2.54);
        return wpfValue / factor;
    }

    // helper converting a length in centimeters to device independent pixels
    public double cmToWpf(double cmValue)
    {
        double factor = (96 / 2.54);
        return cmValue * factor;
    }


    // helper for drawing a figure
    public void drawPathFigure(PathFigure figure, Canvas canvas, Color color)
    {
        PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pathGeometry.Figures.Add(figure);


        Path path = new Path();
        path.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        path.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Miter;
        path.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        path.StrokeThickness = 1;

        path.Data = pathGeometry;
        canvas.Children.Add(path);
    }
}
```

**Issue 2: 100 cm long line cut off on created XPS**

In this second example I am drawing a 100 cm long red line. Obviously it longer than the window size. That's not a problem, the problem is, that it's also cut off on the generated XPS file.

[image: 100 cm long red line]

The generated XPS file looks as follows:
[image: 100 cm long red line on XPS]

The code used for drawing the red line is as follows. As one can see, the red line is simply cut off. I need the full 100 cm red line in the XPS - how can I do that?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MWEXps.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MWEXps"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Sample 2 - 100 cm long red line" Height="300" Width="700">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
        <!-- will be filled by code behind -->        
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Code behind:
(basically only the constructor and printCanvas method are relevant)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // a 100 cm long line
        PathFigure lineFigure1 = new PathFigure();
        lineFigure1.StartPoint = cmPoint(3, 1);

        LineSegment lineSegment1 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment1.Point = cmPoint(103, 1);
        lineFigure1.Segments.Add(lineSegment1);

        drawPathFigure(lineFigure1, canvas, Colors.Red);

        // save as XPS
        printCanvas();
    }


    public void printCanvas()
    {
        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(@".\canvas-100cm.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

        writer.Write(canvas);
        doc.Close();
    }

    // helper creating a point in centimeters
    public Point cmPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        return new Point(cmToWpf(x), cmToWpf(y));
    }


    // helper converting a length in device independent pixels to centimeters
    public double wpfToCm(double wpfValue)
    {
        double factor = (96 / 2.54);
        return wpfValue / factor;
    }

    // helper converting a length in centimeters to device independent pixels
    public double cmToWpf(double cmValue)
    {
        double factor = (96 / 2.54);
        return cmValue * factor;
    }


    // helper for drawing a figure
    public void drawPathFigure(PathFigure figure, Canvas canvas, Color color)
    {
        PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pathGeometry.Figures.Add(figure);


        Path path = new Path();
        path.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        path.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Miter;
        path.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        path.StrokeThickness = 1;

        path.Data = pathGeometry;
        canvas.Children.Add(path);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any support on this!

Comment: Trying calling one of the write methods with a valid PrintTicket. You need tell the printer what size of page you want to draw on and things like the margins and printable areas.  Also, your "100 cm" line is cut off on your MainWindow graphic too.

Comment: With printer, do you mean a real one? I just want to save as XPS (without a dialog). I want to print the complete Canvas content, no matter how much of it is visible, even though in my screenshot one can only see a part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick reminder, **pixel** size depends on two factors: *the display resolution*, and *the physical size* of the monitor, so there are no fixed relation between physical inches and pixels, there for **WPF** used the logical inches and by conversion: One logical inch is **96 pixels** but this can be changed based on the user preferences.

So a "ruler" inch or centimeter doesn't really exist on wpf, only logical ones that deffer from one screen to another.

For example here the size of your black line on two of my screens :

[image]

[image]

2. Regarding the red line, you could fix the canvas size based on its children using the [`Arrange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx) methold, update your `PrintCanvas` method to this:

   ```
     public void printCanvas()
     {
        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(@".\canvas.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
       XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

       // The size of the canvas
       System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(cmToWpf(102), cmToWpf(6));
       // Arrange canvas           
       canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));



       writer.Write(canvas);
       doc.Close();
   }
   ```

---

References

[DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx)

[What measurement units does Silverlight and WPF use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087366/what-measurement-units-does-silverlight-and-wpf-use)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I restructured my initial post. Actually your printCanvas method fixed BOTH problems, though I yet don't understand why it also solved the first problem (10 cm long line ending up as 9.7 cm long line). Do you have any idea, why your solution also fixes the problem with the black line?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly happened right there, it looks like manually calling the arrange method fix some miss-calculations when rendering the canvas and its child elements !

Comment: Accpeting your answer + rewarding bounty. Still interested in the concrete reason, why your reply fixes both problems ;-) Maybe someone else can help us out with that?

Comment: Be aware that canvas.Arrange will cause a memory leak. Call canvas.UpdateLayout() directly after it to prevent memory from leaking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192329/simple-wpf-sample-causes-uncontrolled-memory-growth

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

How do you measure the length of the black line? In case you place a ruler on your screen, you should know, that most screens don't have exactly 96 DPI, but something close to it. Print the document to measure the size.

Problem 2:

You can put your Canvas into a fixed page, and adjust the size of the fixed page to your canvas.

```
var doc = new XpsDocument( "out.xps", FileAccess.Write );
        var xpsdw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter( doc );

        FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();

        FixedPage page = new FixedPage();
        FixedPage.SetLeft( yourCanvas, 0 );
        FixedPage.SetTop( yourCanvas, 0 );

        page.Width = pageWidth;
        page.Height = pageHeight;

        page.Children.Add( yourCanvas );

        page.Measure( new Size( pageWidth, pageHeight ) );
        page.Arrange( new Rect( 0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight ) );
        page.UpdateLayout();


        PageContent page_content = new PageContent();
        ( (IAddChild)page_content ).AddChild( page );

        document.Pages.Add( page_content );

        xpsdw.Write( document );
        doc.Close();
```

Simply adjust the variables "pageWidth" and "pageHeight" to your needs, e.g. yourCanvas.ActualWidth and yourCanvas.ActualHeight.

Be aware, that the XPSViewer doesn't render pages that are too large. The maximum value for each dimension is something around 70000 DiP on my machine.

Comment: Thanks your your reply, I updated my initial post with further information. I am experiencing problems with your code for problem 2. `page.Children.Add( canvas );`gives me a `System.InvalidOperationException`. Note that SamTheDev basically solved both problems (also with shorter code) before investing too much time in an answer. I am still interested in any insight/additional information. Do you see any advantage of your longer code for my use case? Thanks!